# Transformation output `>` instead of `&gt;`

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it! I understand why I need to put the values in nodes, but I'm not working with templates but with functions... I just can't figure out how to put these nodes and templates in a function?

Maybe it's easier if I just show my XSLT file. beneath you can find the file, and let's say for example this could be the $string it passes to the function (of the not transformed XML file):

```
&amp;#x003C;img src=&quot;Afbeeldingen Hotpot/beer.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;afbeelding van een beer&quot; title=&quot;beer&quot; width=&quot;170&quot; height=&quot;144&quot; style=&quot;display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;&quot; style=&quot;float:center;&quot; /&amp;#x003E;
```

This is the complete content of the XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"     xmlns:foo="http://www.wathever.com"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx"
xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">

<xsl:import href="alle-functx-functies.xsl"/>

<xsl:function name="foo:functionIfImage">
    <xsl:param name="string" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($string,'.jpg')">
            <xsl:sequence select="foo:functionImage($string,'.jpg')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($string,'.png')">
            <xsl:sequence select="foo:functionImage($string,'.png')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($string,'.gif')">
            <xsl:sequence select="foo:functionImage($string,'.png')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($string,'.jpg')) and not(contains($string,'.png')) and not(contains($string,'.gif'))">
            <xsl:sequence select="'iumi ondersteund alleen afbeeldingen van het formaat *.jpg, *.png of *.gif'"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($string,'img src='))">
            <xsl:sequence select="'bevat geen img src='"/>
        </xsl:if>

</xsl:function>
<xsl:function name="foo:functionImage">
    <xsl:param name="string" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="type" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:variable name="quot">&quot;</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="beforePath" as="xs:string">img src="</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="globalPath" as="xs:string" select="substring-before(substring-after($string, $beforePath), $quot)" />
        <xsl:variable name="beforeWidth" as="xs:string">width="</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="width" as="xs:string" select="substring-before(substring-after($string, $beforeWidth), $quot)" />
            <xsl:variable name="beforeHeight" as="xs:string">height="</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="height" as="xs:string" select="substring-before(substring-after($string, $beforeHeight), $quot)" />

    <xsl:if test="not(contains($globalPath,'http'))">
        <xsl:variable name="fileName" as="xs:string"><xsl:sequence select="functx:substring-after-last($globalPath,'/')"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="compatibleData" as="xs:string">
            <xsl:sequence select="concat('&lt;img source=&quot;images/',$fileName,'&quot;',' width=&quot;',$width,'&quot; height=&quot;',$height,'&quot; /&gt;')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping= "yes" select="$compatibleData" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($globalPath,'http')">
        <xsl:variable name="compatibleData" as="xs:string">
            <xsl:sequence select="concat('&lt;img source=&quot;',$globalPath,'&quot;',' width=&quot;',$width,'&quot; height=&quot;',$height,'&quot; /&gt;')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping= "yes" select="$compatibleData" />
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So this piece of my XSLT code gives me the wrong output:

```
<xsl:variable name="compatibleData" as="xs:string">
            <xsl:sequence select="concat('&lt;img source=&quot;',$globalPath,'&quot;',' width=&quot;',$width,'&quot; height=&quot;',$height,'&quot; /&gt;')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping= "yes" select="$compatibleData" />
```

Output after transformation:

```
&lt;img source="images/beer.jpg" width="300" height="300" /&gt;
```

Output I want after transformation:

```
<img source="images/beer.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
```

How can I make the output say `<` instead of `&lt;`, and `>` instead of `&gt;`?
value-of disable-output-escaping= "yes" does not work...

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest, easiest and most understandable/maintainable solution :)

Answer (score 6):

> My XSLT code:

```
<xsl:variable name="compatibleData" as="xs:string"><xsl:sequence select="concat('&lt;img source=&quot;images/',$fileName,'&quot;',' width=&quot;',$width,'&quot; height=&quot;',$height,'&quot; /&gt;')"/></xsl:variable>
   <xsl:sequence select="$compatibleData"/>
```

**Never destroy markup by escaping it**!!!

Whenever XSLT is used to generate an XML document, it outputs element (and other types of), **nodes** -- not strings.

**Use**:

```
<img source="images/{$filename}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" />
```

**Explanation**: The use of AVT (**[Attribute-Value-Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**) makes the code shorter and more readable. Always use AVTs when the element and attribute names are known in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to output actual structured (unescaped) XML, so you need to either

- provide the data to XSLT as structured XML (as @Jeff Swensen said), or
- provide the data to XSLT as escaped XML (as you are doing) and then disable escaping on output (as @rsp said). This latter is considered a dirty way of getting XSLT to do what you want without really understanding what's going on; and it may not work, depending on your XSLT processor and what is controlling serialization.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually just type the `<br/>` into your XSLT and it will pass through into the result.

```
<MyElement>
  <xsl:value-of select="/My/Element/Value"/>
  <br/>
</MyElement>
```

Comment: Hmm I don't understand. So I've got to put <br/> in an element or node? Actually this was a simplified code, I've edit my question... is the answer then the same?

Answer (score 1):

Why you try to create variable with tag definition as `xs:string`? It's easy to define variable with element and use it:

```
<xsl:variable name="compatibleData">
    <img source="images/{$filename}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="something">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$compatibleData"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, for the case where you cannot use value-of w/ disable-output-escaping (i.e., in conjunction with copy-of):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet...>
  <xsl:output use-character-maps="special-chars"/>
  <xsl:character-map name="special-chars">
    <xsl:output-character character=">" string="&gt;"/>
  </xsl:character-map>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be looking for:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping= "yes" select="$compatibleData" />
```

Comment: @Dimitre, 1) you might want to read "Eats, Shoots & Leaves" 2) don't downvote valid alternatives according to your likes and dislikes.

Comment: The value of an answer cannot be changed by someone's downvotes, likes or dislikes. See the answer of @LarsH for the shortcomings of you proposed solution. The biggest disadvantage is not only that it goes against the architecture of the XSLT processing model, but because DOE is not a mandatory feature of XSLT and there is no guarantee that a particular XSLT processor supports it at all. As far as I know, the XSLT processor used by FF doesn't support DOE. Based on this, any downvote of a DOE answer is well-founded.